# Wordpress Function Date, difference between POST publish date and POST create Date

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I use a function for my website which shows the Publish Date of the post (get_the_date), but i would like to display the Creation date of the post.

Is there already a function which exist ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, firstly. What code are you using to produce the publish date? What happened when you tried adding this to a post?

Answer (score 1):

yes, there's no separate field for creation date.

Other date fields include
* `post_date_gmt`
* `modified_date`

if you want to save creation date, you can create an admin hook for eg create_post (or similar) that saves the creation date in a meta field, eg `creation_date`, and use that meta field in a filter

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the function `get_the_time()`:

```
echo 'Post created on '.get_the_time('l, F jS, Y', $post->ID).'.';
```

**Output:**

```
Post created on Monday, July 17th, 2017.
```

**More information:**

[Function Reference/get the time – WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)

Answer (score 0):

It display the same date.

My get_the_date_function() :

```
$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time> <time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
}

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date('j F, Y \à\ G:i') ),
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date('j F, Y \à\ G:i') )
);
```

so in my content.php i just call it :

```
<?php myfunction(); ?>
```

output :

```
24 août, 2016 à 17:53
```

If i just call get_the_date it display the same things

```
<?php echo get_the_date('j F, Y \à\ G:i'); ?>
```

output :

```
24 août, 2016 à 17:53
```

Even for get_the_time :

```
Post created on wednesday, août 24th, 2016 at 17:53.
```

But i want display the Create Post date instead of Publish, so the create Post date and Publish post date are the same ?